# WPF coordinate System update

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, coordinate-systems

I created a coordinate system on a canvas Element. I draw for every got value a red point and connect it with the old one.

See here:
[image]

I'm getting every second about 10 values.

1 value = 1 Pixel

The red line represent the values, I'm getting a constant value just for testing.

My goal is to update the drawing when it reaches the end of my coordinate system.
I want push my drawing to the left and draw the next points.

My goal is:

- I dont want lose the points in my graph because later I want to zoom in and out
- I dont want slow down my system as less as possible ...

This is my code but not sure how I can update the graph in the ending part....

```
        static double xOld = 32;
        static double yOld = 580;
        static double t = 32;
        System.Windows.Shapes.Path path;
        static GeometryGroup lineGroupDrw1 = new GeometryGroup();
        ....


  public void drawPoly(double value)
    {

            //increase point position
            t++;


            //generate 2 point for the connection
            Point pOne = new Point(xOld, yOld);
            Point pTwo = new Point(t, value);

            //connect old point with new
            GeometryGroup lineGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            LineGeometry connectorGeometry = new LineGeometry();
            connectorGeometry.StartPoint = pOne;
            connectorGeometry.EndPoint = pTwo;
            lineGroup.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);
            path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
            path.Data = lineGroup;
            path.StrokeThickness = 1;
            path.Stroke = path.Fill = Brushes.Red;


            //fill the static linegroup with a new point
            lineGroupDrw1.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);

            if (coordinateSystem.Width > t)
            {
                // draw graph
                coordinateSystem.Children.Add(path);
            }
            else 
            {
                //To do : update drawing
                updateDrawingEnd();
            }

            //refresh values
            xOld = t;
            yOld = value;

        }
           ....

          public void updateDrawingEnd() 
        {
            path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
            path.Data = lineGroupDrw1;
            path.StrokeThickness = 1;
            path.Stroke = path.Fill = Brushes.Yellow;

            coordinateSystem.Children.Add(path);
            t = 145;
        }
```

Comment: Post your full code and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your UI inside a scrollviewer. Forget about trying to "move" the lines around.

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.SignalGraph"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SignalGraph" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="coordinateSystem">

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Code Behind (taken from your code and improved a little bit)

```
 public partial class SignalGraph : Window
    {
        private System.Threading.Timer timer;
        private Random random = new Random();

        public SignalGraph()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x => DrawRandomLine(), null, 0, 100);
        }

        private void DrawRandomLine()
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => drawPoly(random.Next(0,100))), null);
        }

        static double xOld = 32;
        static double yOld = 580;
        static double t = 32;
        Path path;
        static GeometryGroup lineGroupDrw1 = new GeometryGroup();

        public void drawPoly(double value)
        {
            //increase point position
            t = t+5;


            //generate 2 point for the connection
            var pOne = new Point(xOld, yOld);
            var pTwo = new Point(t, value);

            //connect old point with new
            var lineGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            var connectorGeometry = new LineGeometry {StartPoint = pOne, EndPoint = pTwo};

            lineGroup.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);
            path = new Path
                       {
                           Data = lineGroup, 
                           StrokeThickness = 1,
                           Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                           Fill = Brushes.Red
                       };

            //fill the static linegroup with a new point
            lineGroupDrw1.Children.Add(connectorGeometry);

            //if (coordinateSystem.ActualWidth > t)
            //{
                // draw graph
                coordinateSystem.Children.Add(path);
            //}
            //else 
            //{
            //    //To do : update drawing
            //    updateDrawingEnd();
            //}

            //refresh values
            xOld = t;
            yOld = value;

        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would consider developing a specific user control to display the chart and use a separate class for the chart data representation. You could use a simple List or create a specific class providing more features. This way, you can keep the record of all points separately from the UI concerns (like how to keep in memory the points that are no more displayed for further use).
You could bind your chart object to your user control and, in this control, develop specific logic to handle zoom, show previous points and so on...